# Keydown + switch case, why this code doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, key, keydown

I try to write a JS code where, when I press some letters keys on my keyboard or when I click on buttons symbolizing these same letters (each button has a class name with one of these letters), this plays a sound.

I don't understand why the following code concretely doesn't work:

```js
var numberOfButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".drum");

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfButtons.length; i++) {

  numberOfButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    var buttonHTML = this.textContent;
    makeSound(buttonHTML);
  });

  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    makeSound(event.key);
  });

  function makeSound(key) {
    switch (key) {
      case "w":
        var tom1 = new Audio('sounds/tom-1.mp3');
        tom1.play();
        break;

      case "a":
        var tom2 = new Audio('sounds/tom-2.mp3');
        tom2.play();
        break;

      case "s":
        var tom3 = new Audio('sounds/tom-3.mp3');
        tom3.play();
        break;

      case "d":
        var tom4 = new Audio('sounds/tom-4.mp3');
        tom4.play();
        break;

      case "j":
        var snare = new Audio('sounds/snare.mp3');
        snare.play();
        break;

      case "k":
        var crash = new Audio('sounds/crash.mp3');
        crash.play();
        break;

      case "l":
        var kick = new Audio('sounds/kick-bass.mp3');
        kick.play();
        break;

      default:
        console.log(event.key);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You need to tag what language that is.

Comment: Thanks. It's in JS

Comment: Ok but you need to put the tag in.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now that I had to tag it in the tag lidt. I did it.

Comment: I've fixed your snippet; you had placed your JavaScript in the HTML box; it's not going to work there :). Now you need to add some elements with the class "drum" so the code will run. Note that you could put a close curly bracket `}` after the first `addEventListener` call to make the JavaScript valid.

Comment: class drum elements are as follows in HTML: <div class="set">
    <button class="w drum">w</button>
    <button class="a drum">a</button>
    <button class="s drum">s</button>
    <button class="d drum">d</button>
    <button class="j drum">j</button>
    <button class="k drum">k</button>
    <button class="l drum">l</button>
  </div>

Comment: And I did put the curly brackets after my addEventListener. Unless I misunderstood your question?